# Deactivate Gtag in Angular App on user-opt-out / based on cookie-policy

Tags: angular, google-analytics, gtag.js

I implemented a cookie-policy banner with settings for tracking-cookies. Therefore in the next step I need to decide, whether to "use" or not use google-analytics (gtag) during runtime.

Google advises to deactivate gtag be adding a property to the window  Object (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-opt-out).

```
window['ga-disable-GA_MEASUREMENT_ID'] = true;
```

As you browse through the web there are a lot of discussion on how to access the window object, since it can cause problems e.g. during Server-Side-Rendering. But a solution using a Factory and a lot of code seems to big for my little problem: https://brianflove.com/2018/01/11/angular-window-provider/

What I basically want to do now is this:

```
  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){
        window['ga-disable-'+environment.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID] = true;
      }
```

The solutions works, but I am not sure if this is a "valid solution", please advise on better approaches

Answer (score 0):

I would decouple the problem from the service so that you can effectively test this, and then worry about server side rendering and window references elsewhere.

I'd achieve this by creating a custom injectable object.

```js
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export interface GoogleSettings {
   'ga-disable-GA_MEASUREMENT_ID'?: boolean;
}

export const GOOGLE_SETTINGS: InjectionToken<GoogleSettings> = new InjectionToken<GoogleSettings>('GOOGLE_SETTINGS');
```

You would then use that interface in your service.

```js
@Injectable()
export class GoogleService {
   public constructor(@Inject(GOOGLE_SETTINGS) settings: GoogleSettings) {
       settings['ga-disable-GA_MEASUREMENT_ID'] = true;
   }
}
```

Now you can inject this custom object *only in the web browser* via the `main.ts` file that bootstraps the application.

```js
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
     providers: [
        {provide: GOOGLE_SETTINGS, useValue: window}
     ]
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

When you are ready to do server side rendering (SSR), then that will use a *different* bootstrap function and you can provide a different value (for example; `{}` an empty object). There will be no TypeScript compiler warnings for an *unknown* type on SSR for the `Window` class, because you never reference it with SSR.